# Why can't Odin recognize the phone in system recovery?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader, odin

If I boot the phone in system recovery, it doesn't detect the phone:

[image]

But when I boot the phone normally, Odin can detect it:

[image]

If I flash TWRP recovery anyway, the log is:

```
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1005)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
```

and it's stuck there (which makes sense).

I have unlocked OEM and USB debugging. More Information:

- **Odin version:** 3
- **Phone:** Samsung J1-6 J120H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because **VOLUME UP**+HOME+POWER is to access Recovery Mode, while to access Download Mode the key combination is **VOLUME DOWN**+HOME+POWER. This is the correct screenshot of the Download Mode:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fonepaw.com](https://www.fonepaw.com/images/solution/download-mode-samsung.jpg))</sub>

See more: [How To Enter Samsung Recovery/Download Mode](https://www.fonepaw.com/solution/enter-samsung-recovery-download-mode.html)